# VS Code find what filename color means

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason one of my files in VS Code turned dim. Is there a way to find out what this color means?

In the image, SearchBar.tsx is a dim green, and I have no idea why. It's not .gitignored (dist/ and node_modules/ are in the image). Is there any way to find out what this color means?

[image: VS Code explorer]

Comment: As I wrote in the question, it is not .gitignored. You can see in the image that is currently added to the index. It's something different.

Comment: what does the tooltip of the file give you

Comment: Well now its stopped and it looks the same as all the other files. But what I really wanted was to know where this stuff is defined so I could look it up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `A` means staged. `M` means modified in working directory (staged or not)